# Issue with Bootstrap 3 dropdown menus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My dropdown menus are working fine however the issue I'm having is that when you hover over the links in the actual dropdown menu, the parent link and text turns black. I would like it to remain the same background and text color as the rollover.  I've tried changing the background, text color and hover styles on the dropdown-toggle with no change.

Here's a bootply with my code: http://www.bootply.com/127174

Answer (score -1):

Posted this to the DC Web Women list first thing this morning and got the answer within a few minutes.  I just wanted to add it here in case someone else has this same issue:

It's right here:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse
.navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
background-color: #080808;
color: #fff;
}
```

looks like you're overwriting it for the subnavigation but the same rules
apply to the topnav because it's telling the menu, "When I hover over a
link under this "open" class, turn ALL the links directly related to the
class (in this case, the topnav) black in the background."

I added the above style to my own stylesheet and changed the background color to the same as my hover background and it worked.  The font color is still black but I can live with that.  [DC Web Women](http://www.dcwebwomen.org/) rule!